# PHP Math captcha not passing

Tags: php, captcha

I'm trying to make a simple math captcha for users on registering.
But the problem is that it's always returning the message invalid captcha.
New to this and not sure what's wrong.

```
<?php

namespace forum;

require_once 'core/database.php';
require_once 'classes/Redirect.php';

Class Captcha{

    public static function Captcha($sol){

        $random = rand(1, 15);


        if (empty($sol)) {
            return 'What is ' . $random . ' + ' . $random . ' ';
        }

        $answer = $random + $random;

        if ($sol != $answer)
        {
            return false;


        } else {

            return true;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That is because on every call to `Captcha::Captcha()` the solution changes, so, the solution provided becomes invalid.

Comment: Also you should be getting: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Constructor Captcha::Captcha() cannot be static

Comment: No, I'm not getting that error.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone No he shouldn't

Comment: @mega6382 https://3v4l.org/H4Q1n

Comment: @LawrenceCherone OK, but I am not getting that error, on PHP 7.1

Comment: You removed parts of the code.. No wonder it's throwing errors now,
Nor do you have the files included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

```
Class Captcha
{
    public static function Captcha($sol = null)
    {
        $random = rand(1, 15);


        if (empty($sol))
        {
            $answer = $random + $random;
            $_SESSION['captchaAnswer'] = $answer;
            return 'What is ' . $random . ' + ' . $random . ' ';
        }

        if ($sol == $_SESSION['captchaAnswer'])
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This will store the answer in the session and will check against that answer for the solution. This is not the best way, you can try using something more secure, like ReCaptcha.